# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'geometry'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, geometry, toplevel

I've created a toplevel window in my Tkinter program. However it just doesn't seem to get the geometry part.

Some of the code:

```
 def calreco():
        calreco_screen = Toplevel(cc)
        calreco_screen.title("Your Recommended Calorie Intake Is")
        calreco.geometry("400x400")
```

Comment: `calreco_screen.geometry(...)`.

Comment: `calreco` is the function name

Answer (score 1):

You are initiated and called a different/unknown object.

```
calreco.geometry("400x400")
```

Instead, Try

```
calreco_screen.geometry("400x400")
```

This could solve your issue.